# Validating 2 out of 8 true/false checkboxes or checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My form has 4 true/false questions and it needs 1 true selection and 1 false, 2 selection in total, to be valid. The accepted scenarios would be the following:

1. `□ true - □ false`
2. `☒ true - □ false`
3. `□ true - □ false`
4. `□ true - ☒ false`

or

1. `□ true - ☒ false`
2. `□ true - □ false`
3. `□ true - □ false`
4. `☒ true - □ false`

Logic:

- there must be only 1 true and only 1 false answer (2 answers in total).
- there can't be more than 1 false and 1 true answer.
- there can't be 1 true and 1 false answer for the same questions.
- return true when all these rules are met.
- in the last example's form:

  1. `□ true - ☒ false`
  2. `□ true - □ false`
  3. `□ true - □ false`
  4. `☒ true - □ false`

if one clicks 'true' on question number 1 the following scenario will
   occur:

- `☒ true - □ false`
- `□ true - □ false`
- `□ true - □ false`
- `□ true - □ false`

the other value (false) of the same row gets unchecked and the other option of the same value (true) gets unchecked so that the initial conditions (see above logic) are always met at every event.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <p>1) 
        <input name="q1" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="q1" type="checkbox" value="false">
    </p>
    <p>2) 
        <input name="q2" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="q2" type="checkbox" value="false">
    </p>
    <p>3) 
        <input name="q3" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="q3" type="checkbox" value="false">
    </p>
    <p>4) 
        <input name="q4" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="q4" type="checkbox" value="false">
    </p>
</form>
```

The form needs to validate (i.e. autoupdate) on every click event.

Comment: would be great if you can share the html.

Comment: I would use radio button instead of checkbox. that way your third rule is valid all the time.

Comment: Have you tried it, or you want an cooked product. Share your effort here so that someone can understand your efforts.

Comment: Good Question we need html to validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
if($('input:first-child:checked').length==1){
   var firstcheckedelementindex=$('input:first-child').index($('input:first-child:checked'));
    var secondcheckedelementindex=$('input:nth-child(2)').filter(function(){
    return this.checked;
}).length;
return( secondcheckedelementindex==1 && $('input:nth-child(2)').not(':eq('+firstcheckedelementindex+')').is(':checked'))
}else{
   return false;
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bc85psuy/)**

Comment: you missed something check my answer.

Comment: if select false 2 times and true 1 times then return true.

Comment: can you please implement the checkbox on click event?

Comment: if one clicks 'true' on question number 1 of the latter example, the result should be one selected option only

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes, that checkbox should get unchecked thanks!

Comment: it should be a function that, at every event, it unchecks all other checkboxes of the same kind, both the ones with the same name and with the same class

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, no because the js you provided here:   jsfiddle.net/sjj5bz9t still allows true and false to be checked on the same paragraph. i added a class that we can use to sort that out. the js should, at every event, uncheck all the checkboxes of the same name and class

Comment: @MilindAnantwar i changed the checkboxes to radio buttons and it works like a charm! http://jsfiddle.net/maustyle/je2k460z/4/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar can i post the corrected answer on your behalf please?

Comment: I completed edited your answer @MilindAnantwar, thanks. what's next? should we delete our own obsolete comments? or make these comments obsolete? or just move the comments to a chat?